# My former boss keeps looking at my Linkedin profile, what to do?

Tags: job-change, linkedin

**Context:**

I left my previous job about one year ago. I made that decision because:

- Job was VERY stressfull
- I wasn't working the topic I was interested in (even though in my interviews I was explicitely told that I was going to do that)
- I was paid less then promised
- Most of all, my former boss is a control freak

So, as already mentioned, I left that job one year ago. When I told him I was quitting, I clearly mentioned all the reasons that I just wrote some lines ago. At first he was a mix between surprised and sad, while after a couple of days his normal temper came back. Just notice that I never regretted my decision, not even for a second. In fact, I think that was the best professional decision I made in my entire life.

The thing is, since that moment, he started visiting my Linkedin profile regularly, I would say more or less twice a month.

That is really annoying. I honestly can't tell if he's doing that because he felt betrayed by me or because he hopes to see me fail (not that I care that much, tbh). Of course I removed him from my contacts, hoping that this would remove the notifications of him visiting, but that didn't work, or at least not entirely. I was considering blocking him, since I'm sure I don't want anything to do with him ever again, but I'm pretty sure he would create a fake profile and keep peeping at my profile.

**So, finally, my question is:**

What would you guys do? Block him? Just ignore him? I wonder if someone got the same experience and how they handled that. I was even thinking about texting him "*Hey, I noticed you keep looking at my profile, ya need something?*", but maybe the best thing to do is just let go.

Comment: So, just how much time are you wasting checking up on him and then writing about it on here?

Comment: With all due respect, your post is along the same  lines someone would right abouts a stalking ex.  You need to work to un-attach yourself emotionally from your previous situation and its participants.

Comment: Yes; Block the individual

Comment: @SolarMike writing this post about 20 minutes, checking up on him zero, I just see it when I open my Linkedin notifications. Anyway, I get your point.

Comment: Turn on private mode for browsing profiles, as a side effect you won't be able to see who's looking at your profile.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Ignore it.**

Linkedin profiles are meant to be looked at. He's not doing anything wrong. The only problem is it's effect on you, and that wouldn't happen if you ignored it.

Unless you are actively looking for a job I would suggest not checking who is looking at your profile anyway. It doesn't help you much. At least disable the notifications so your attention isn't drawn to it.

Comment: The most annoying thing about LinkedIn is those dang notifications that someone viewed your profile. Should just go away.

Comment: @LukeSawczak you can disable them, that's what I did

Answer (score 6):

**Block him.**

No need to give this a second thought.

It's a distraction for you. If he creates a second profile to keep peeping, you'll never know, and that's fine.

What you shouldn't have to deal with is see his name come up over and over again.

All a fan of the other answer that says to **Ignore it.** but us humans are fickle beasts. If the block helps you do it, then block.

Comment: +1 I never understand why people are so hesitant to use blocking features.

Comment: Wrong! My blocking him you message him that he is still important to you and that you give him power over you. The OP needs to get over it.

Comment: @Hilmar At this stage, it's just a pointless distraction for the OP. One that's easy to eliminate with the block. If you are concerned what they think about the block, then you are still giving them power over you.

Comment: Blocking would also make it clear that further contact is not welcome without needed to engage. Regardless, @SilentCloud you should also review your privacy options and restrict a lot of the information on your profile to your connections.